# Bash regex test not working

Tags: bash

```
echo "Enter username"
read $WORD

if [[ "$WORD" =~ ^(Dale|Paul|Ray)$ ]]; then
    echo "$WORD is valid"
else
    echo "$WORD is invalid"
fi
```

Comment: I did format it like that, for some reason when I typed it here it changed. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in `read` command, use `read WORD` instead of `read $WORD`.

Check this:

```
echo "Enter username"
read WORD

if [[ "$WORD" =~ ^(Dale|Paul|Ray)$ ]]; then
    echo "$WORD is valid"
else
    echo "$WORD is invalid"
fi
```